# PHP Reference - What does this piece of code do?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the next pice of code property of the CodeIgniter framework source:

```php
class CI_Controller {

    private static $instance;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$instance =& $this;

        foreach (is_loaded() as $var => $class)
        {
            $this -> $var =& load_class( $class ) ;
        }

        $this -> load =& load_class('Loader', 'core') ;
        $this -> load -> initialize() ;
        log_message('info', 'Controller Class Initialized') ;
    }

    public static function &get_instance()
    {
        return self::$instance;
    }

}
```

At this part Is it not a reference by itself "$this"? Why do they use the & symbol.

```php
self::$instance =& $this;
```

And the other thing I do not understand is in the foreach block of code.

The '$var' variable to whom is linked? I do not see any defintion of that inside the class, so why to use the $this reference with it.

Could someone explain me this please? ...

I am new inside the PHP world.

Comment: It's probably old code and the reference is not needed any more.

Answer (score 0):

```
self::$instance =& $this;
```

I don't thin the `&` is needed here. Objects are always assigned as references rather than copied. This might be a relic left from an older version of PHP that needed it.

```
            $this -> $var =& load_class( $class ) ;
```

This is creating a new property whose name is in `$var`, and makes it a reference to the class.

`is_loaded()` returns an associative array that maps property names to class names, and the loop loads all those classes and assigns them to the properties.